# How to sort magento attribute value by position

Tags: magento

How to Sort magento attribute value by position, the case is

Size Attribute

S position 0
M position 1
L position 2
XL position 3

But it always shown alphabetically like L, M, S, XL in layered navigation

Cheers

Comment: have you set any sort order of those attribute options ??

Comment: Yes the value position already like i wrote above @karan-adhikari

Comment: Sorting in a dropdown, or in a product listing?